# What is the advantage of using both TypeScript and Traceur?

Tags: compilation, typescript, ecmascript-6, traceur

You can configure TypeScript to output either ES5 or ES6. As long as you want to run your application on a platform that does not natively support ES6 you must compile the ES6 to ES5 using a compiler like Traceur (and including the Traceur runtime library).

Is there any advantage of doing this rather than simply telling TypeScript to output ES5? (I don't expect that the application will ever target native ES6 platforms only)

As far as I have understood you cannot write a program in TypeScript (1.5) that cannot run on ES5 (given that the program compiles and you include the correct libraries). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Reasons to use Babel or Traceur over TypeScript

So far, the team of Typescript chose not to make the generated code dependent of a runtime. Some features of ES6 can easily be used with TS through polyfills (example: ES6 Promises). Other features require the cooperation of the transpiler and a polyfill (example: ES6 generators). Using a generator with TS is possible (since TS 1.6) but the target must be ES6. That's a good reason to use Babel or Traceur.

## Reasons to *not* use Babel or Traceur over TypeScript

But there are other good reasons for not using Babel and Traceur. Just try to transpile some ES6 code.

The ES6 code:

```
let list = ['ab', 'cd'];
for (let item of list) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

ES5 produced by TypeScript (using [the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/)):

```
var list = ['ab', 'cd'];
for (var _i = 0; _i < list.length; _i++) {
      var item = list[_i];
      console.log(item);
}
```

ES5 produced by Traceur (using [the REPL](https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/demo/repl.html)):

```
$traceurRuntime.ModuleStore.getAnonymousModule(function() {
    "use strict";
    var list = ['ab', 'cd'];
    var $__4 = true;
    var $__5 = false;
    var $__6 = undefined;
    try {
      for (var $__2 = void 0,
          $__1 = (list)[$traceurRuntime.toProperty(Symbol.iterator)](); !($__4 = ($__2 = $__1.next()).done); $__4 = true) {
        var item = $__2.value;
        {
          console.log(item);
        }
      }
    } catch ($__7) {
      $__5 = true;
      $__6 = $__7;
    } finally {
      try {
        if (!$__4 && $__1.return != null) {
          $__1.return();
        }
      } finally {
        if ($__5) {
          throw $__6;
        }
      }
    }
    return {};
});
//# sourceURL=traceured.js
```

ES5 produced by Babel (using [the REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/)):

```
'use strict';

var list = ['ab', 'cd'];
var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
var _didIteratorError = false;
var _iteratorError = undefined;

try {
    for (var _iterator = list[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
        var item = _step.value;

        console.log(item);
    }
} catch (err) {
    _didIteratorError = true;
    _iteratorError = err;
} finally {
    try {
        if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator['return']) {
            _iterator['return']();
        }
    } finally {
        if (_didIteratorError) {
            throw _iteratorError;
        }
    }
}
```

The solutions from Traceur and Babel are ugly, because the variable `list` could be [an ES6 iterable](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/04/es6-in-depth-iterators-and-the-for-of-loop/) and these transpilers aren't aware of the types. TypeScript infers that the type of `list` is an array `string[]` and it produces just the code for the array.

Comment: So this seems to be an argument for using the ES5 flag in TypeScript. But my main question was if there is any good reason to do it the other way, using the ES6 flag and then Traceur.

Comment: ok, so is it possible to write a program in TypeScript that will compile without errors to ES5, but will not actually be runnable on ES5, if you use an ES6 feature such as ES6 Promises?

Comment: To partially answer my own comment: If you use ES6 Promises, the TypeScript compiler will generate errors IF you have the ES5 flag set, but not if you have the ES6 flag. So the compiler reports differently depending on the target.
Again: is there any way of writing a program that will compile with ES5 but not be runnable on ES5?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn You can use ES6 promises with the ES5 target. You just have to declare the objet `Promise`, or to use [the definition file from DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts). The compiler doesn't need a definition file for ES6 target because in an ES6 environment, the variable `Promise` is a standard.

Comment: For using ES6 promises on ES5 browser (with or without TS), you need to load [a polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise).